# How to Set a Default Arrange Type in OS X Lion?

Tags: osx-lion, finder

I'm having trouble setting a default arrange type in Mac OS X Lion.
I remember doing it in Snow Leopard very long time ago but I forgot it.

Comment: What is an "arrange type"?

Answer (score 24):

Finder works the same way (just be sure you open a real folder and try editing the view options from the Desktop as that one window has abbreviated controls.)

- Open any Finder folder
- <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> **Show View Options**
- make your changes
- select the **Use as defaults** button at the bottom of the floating window

[image]

Comment: Strange... there's no "Use as Defaults" button for me. I'm sure I'm looking at a "real folder". Anyone else missing this button?

Comment: Usually this happens when you are operating on the Desktop or another "special" folder like All My Files and not an arbitrary folder.

Comment: This "Use as Defaults" option appears to save it only for THAT specific folder, and not all folders on the computer. Setting this doesn't change any other folder. I can't seem to find any way to actually set one folder's view setup, as a global default for all other folders. It's rather maddening.

Comment: @Jonathan the OS will first respect whatever setting is established in the current directories .DS_Store file, so perhaps you are looking at folders that already have ase

Comment: @Jonathan - the OS respects any custom settings stored in .DS_Store files for each directory before the "default" settings apply. You could crawl the file system and delete these if you want everything to respect the new "defaults".

Comment: "Use as Default" does not apply to "Arrange By"